# Microsoft Office interop performance issue

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, office-2007, winforms-interop

I am try to exporting datagridview data to excel file in my C# 4.0 Windows application.

we used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll version 12.0.0.0. It's works well and everything

is fine. But i when i try to export more than 1000 datagridview records it's take too long

time.How can i improve the performance.

Please see this Excel helper code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // For COMException
using System.Reflection; // For Missing.Value and BindingFlags
using System.Diagnostics; // to ensure EXCEL process is really killed

namespace Export.Excel
{

    #region InstanceFields

    //Instance Fields
    //public delegate void ProgressHandler(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e);
    //public event ProgressHandler prg;
    private System.Data.DataView dv;
    private Style styleRows;
    private Style styleColumnHeadings;
    private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application EXL;
    private Workbook workbook;
    private Sheets sheets;
    private Worksheet worksheet;
    private string[,] myTemplateValues;
    private int position;
    private System.Globalization.CultureInfo cl;
    private Type _ResourceType;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    //Constructs a new export2Excel object. The user must
    //call the createExcelDocument method once a valid export2Excel
    //object has been instantiated

    public ExportExcelFormat(string culture, Type type)
    {
        cl = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
        _ResourceType = type;
    }

    #endregion


    #region EXCEL : ExportToExcel
    //Exports a DataView to Excel. The following steps are carried out
    //in order to export the DataView to Excel
    //Create Excel Objects
    //Create Column & Row Workbook Cell Rendering Styles
    //Fill Worksheet With DataView
    //Add Auto Shapes To Excel Worksheet
    //Select All Used Cells
    //Create Headers/Footers
    //Set Status Finished
    //Save workbook & Tidy up all objects
    //@param dv : DataView to use
    //@param path : The path to save/open the EXCEL file to/from
    //@param sheetName : The target sheet within the EXCEL file
    public void ExportToExcel(System.Data.DataView dv, string path, string sheetName, string[] UnWantedColumns)
    {
        try
        {
            //Assign Instance Fields
            this.dv = dv;

            #region NEW EXCEL DOCUMENT : Create Excel Objects

            //create new EXCEL application
            EXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
            //index to hold location of the requested sheetName in the workbook sheets
            //collection
            int indexOfsheetName;

            #region FILE EXISTS
            //Does the file exist for the given path
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {

                //Yes file exists, so open the file
                workbook = EXL.Workbooks.Open(path,
                    0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                    true, false, 0, true, false, false);

                //get the workbook sheets collection
                sheets = workbook.Sheets;

                //set the location of the requested sheetName to -1, need to find where
                //it is. It may not actually exist
                indexOfsheetName = -1;

                //loop through the sheets collection
                for (int i = 1; i <= sheets.Count; i++)
                {
                    //get the current worksheet at index (i)
                    worksheet = (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(i);

                    //is the current worksheet the sheetName that was requested
                    if (worksheet.Name.ToString().Equals(sheetName))
                    {
                        //yes it is, so store its index
                        indexOfsheetName = i;

                        //Select all cells, and clear the contents
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myAllRange = worksheet.Cells;
                        myAllRange.Select();
                        myAllRange.CurrentRegion.Select();
                        myAllRange.ClearContents();
                    }
                }

                //At this point it is known that the sheetName that was requested
                //does not exist within the found file, so create a new sheet within the
                //sheets collection
                if (indexOfsheetName == -1)
                {
                    //Create a new sheet for the requested sheet
                    Worksheet sh = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.Add(
                        Type.Missing, (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(sheets.Count),
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    //Change its name to that requested
                    sh.Name = sheetName;
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region FILE DOESNT EXIST
            //No the file DOES NOT exist, so create a new file
            else
            {
                //Add a new workbook to the file
                workbook = EXL.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
                //get the workbook sheets collection
                sheets = workbook.Sheets;
                //get the new sheet
                worksheet = (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
                //Change its name to that requested
                worksheet.Name = sheetName;
            }
            #endregion

            #region get correct worksheet index for requested sheetName

            //get the workbook sheets collection
            sheets = workbook.Sheets;

            //set the location of the requested sheetName to -1, need to find where
            //it is. It will definately exist now as it has just been added
            indexOfsheetName = -1;

            //loop through the sheets collection
            for (int i = 1; i <= sheets.Count; i++)
            {
                //get the current worksheet at index (i)
                worksheet = (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(i);



                //is the current worksheet the sheetName that was requested
                if (worksheet.Name.ToString().Equals(sheetName))
                {
                    //yes it is, so store its index
                    indexOfsheetName = i;
                }
            }

            //set the worksheet that the DataView should write to, to the known index of the
            //requested sheet
            worksheet = (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(indexOfsheetName);
            #endregion

            #endregion

            // Set styles 1st
            SetUpStyles();
            //Fill EXCEL worksheet with DataView values
            fillWorksheet_WithDataView(UnWantedColumns);
            //Add the autoshapes to EXCEL
            //AddAutoShapesToExcel();
            //Select all used cells within current worksheet
            SelectAllUsedCells();

            try
            {
                workbook.Close(true, path, Type.Missing);
                EXL.UserControl = false;
                EXL.Quit();
                EXL = null;
                //kill the EXCEL process as a safety measure
                killExcel();
            }
            catch (COMException cex)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region EXCEL : UseTemplate
    //Exports a DataView to Excel. The following steps are carried out
    //in order to export the DataView to Excel
    //Create Excel Objects And Open Template File
    //Select All Used Cells
    //Create Headers/Footers
    //Set Status Finished
    //Save workbook & Tidy up all objects
    //@param path : The path to save/open the EXCEL file to/from
    public void UseTemplate(string path, string templatePath, string[,] myTemplateValues)
    {
        try
        {
            this.myTemplateValues = myTemplateValues;
            //create new EXCEL application
            EXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
            //Yes file exists, so open the file
            workbook = EXL.Workbooks.Open(templatePath,
                0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                true, false, 0, true, false, false);
            //get the workbook sheets collection
            sheets = workbook.Sheets;
            //get the new sheet
            worksheet = (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);
            //Change its name to that requested
            worksheet.Name = "ATemplate";
            //Fills the Excel Template File Selected With A 2D Test Array
            fillTemplate_WithTestValues();
            //Select all used cells within current worksheet
            SelectAllUsedCells();

            try
            {
                workbook.Close(true, path, Type.Missing);
                EXL.UserControl = false;
                EXL.Quit();
                EXL = null;
                //kill the EXCEL process as a safety measure
                killExcel();
            }
            catch (COMException)
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region STEP 1 : Create Column & Row Workbook Cell Rendering Styles
    //Creates 2 Custom styles for the workbook These styles are
    //  styleColumnHeadings
    //  styleRows
    //These 2 styles are used when filling the individual Excel cells with the
    //DataView values. If the current cell relates to a DataView column heading
    //then the style styleColumnHeadings will be used to render the current cell.
    //If the current cell relates to a DataView row then the style styleRows will
    //be used to render the current cell.
    private void SetUpStyles()
    {
        // Style styleColumnHeadings
        try
        {
            styleColumnHeadings = workbook.Styles["styleColumnHeadings"];
        }
        // Style doesn't exist yet.
        catch
        {
            styleColumnHeadings = workbook.Styles.Add("styleColumnHeadings", Type.Missing);
            styleColumnHeadings.Font.Name = "Arial";
            styleColumnHeadings.Font.Size = 12;
            styleColumnHeadings.Font.Bold = true;
        }

        // Style styleRows
        try
        {

            styleRows = workbook.Styles["styleRows"];
        }
        // Style doesn't exist yet.
        catch
        {
            styleRows = workbook.Styles.Add("styleRows", Type.Missing);
            styleRows.Font.Name = "Verdana";
            styleRows.Font.Size = 9;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region STEP 2 : Fill Worksheet With DataView
    //Fills an Excel worksheet with the values contained in the DataView
    //parameter
    private void fillWorksheet_WithDataView(string[] UnWantedColumns)
    {
        position = 0;
        //Add DataView Columns To Worksheet
        int row = 1;
        int col = 1;
        // Remove unwanted columns in the loop
        int total = dv.Table.Columns.Count - UnWantedColumns.Count();
        // Loop thought the columns
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {

            fillExcelCell(worksheet, row, col++, dv.Table.Columns[i].ToString(), styleColumnHeadings.Name, UnWantedColumns);
        }

        //Add DataView Rows To Worksheet
        row = 2;
        col = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < dv.Table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < dv.Table.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                fillExcelCell(worksheet, row, col++, dv[i][j].ToString(), styleRows.Name, UnWantedColumns);
            }
            col = 1;
            row++;

            position = (100 / dv.Table.Rows.Count) * row + 2;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region STEP 3 : Fill Individual Cell and Render Using Predefined Style
    //Formats the current cell based on the Style setting parameter name
    //provided here
    //@param worksheet : The worksheet
    //@param row : Current row
    //@param col : Current Column
    //@param Value : The value for the cell
    //@param StyleName : The style name to use
    private void fillExcelCell(Worksheet worksheet, int row, int col, Object Value, string StyleName, string[] UnWantedColumns)
    {
        if (!UnWantedColumns.Contains(Value.ToString()))
        {
            Range rng = (Range)worksheet.Cells[row, col];
            rng.NumberFormat = "@";
            rng.Select();
            rng.Value2 = Value.ToString();
            rng.Style = StyleName;
            rng.Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region STEP 4 : Add Auto Shapes To Excel Worksheet
    //Add some WordArt objecs to the Excel worksheet
    private void AddAutoShapesToExcel()
    {
        //Method fields
        float txtSize = 80;
        float Left = 100.0F;
        float Top = 100.0F;
        //Have 2 objects
        int[] numShapes = new int[2];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape[] myShapes = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape[numShapes.Length];

        try
        {
            //loop through the object count
            for (int i = 0; i < numShapes.Length; i++)
            {

                //Add the object to Excel
                myShapes[i] = worksheet.Shapes.AddTextEffect(MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, "DRAFT", "Arial Black",
                    txtSize, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, (Left * (i * 3)), Top);

                //Manipulate the object settings
                myShapes[i].Rotation = 45F;
                myShapes[i].Fill.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
                myShapes[i].Fill.Transparency = 0F;
                myShapes[i].Line.Weight = 1.75F;
                myShapes[i].Line.DashStyle = MsoLineDashStyle.msoLineSolid;
                myShapes[i].Line.Transparency = 0F;
                myShapes[i].Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
                myShapes[i].Line.ForeColor.RGB = (0 << 16) | (0 << 8) | 0;
                myShapes[i].Line.BackColor.RGB = (255 << 16) | (255 << 8) | 255;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

    }
    #endregion

    #region STEP 5 : Select All Used Cells
    //Selects all used cells for the Excel worksheet
    private void SelectAllUsedCells()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myAllRange = worksheet.Cells;
        myAllRange.Select();
        myAllRange.CurrentRegion.Select();
    }
    #endregion

    #region STEP 6 : Fill Template With Test Values
    //Fills the Excel Template File Selected With A 2D Test Array parameter
    private void fillTemplate_WithTestValues()
    {
        //Initilaise the correct Start Row/Column to match the Template
        int StartRow = 3;
        int StartCol = 2;

        position = 0;

        // Display the array elements within the Output window, make sure its correct before
        for (int i = 0; i <= myTemplateValues.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            //loop through array and put into EXCEL template
            for (int j = 0; j <= myTemplateValues.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                //update position in progress bar
                position = (100 / myTemplateValues.Length) * i;

                //put into EXCEL template
                Range rng = (Range)worksheet.Cells[StartRow, StartCol++];
                rng.Select();
                rng.Value2 = myTemplateValues[i, j].ToString();
                rng.Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit();
            }
            //New row, so column needs to be reset
            StartCol = 2;
            StartRow++;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Kill EXCEL
    //As a safety check go through all processes and make
    //doubly sure excel is shutdown. Working with COM
    //have sometimes noticed that the EXL.Quit() call
    //does always do the job
    private void killExcel()
    {
        try
        {
            Process[] ps = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process p in ps)
            {
                if (p.ProcessName.ToLower().Equals("excel"))
                {
                    p.Kill();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: After a lot of issues I moved to XML formats: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats

Comment: Thank you for your valueable reply. In this method i get full control in the column width and height and Numberformat in cells. You mean change this to XML formats

Comment: Even the XML format does, and you not need excel installed and a lot of references. Yes you need an extra work to set cells style/formatting. But it would be much faster and lighter... That's only my opinion :-)

Comment: Thank you very much.
I using Microsoft Office XML formats method in my appliction for exporting griddata to Excel format.It's really fast.
But facing  a issues with accent vowels. It's not properly converted in this method. any suggestions please ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have a few suggestions to improve the performance. Singly they may not have much impact, but together they should improve overall performance.

- Hide Excel (if it isn't already) `EXL.Visible = false;`. Turn off
  `Calculation` (`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`, if it
  isn't needed) and `ScreenUpdating` as well.
- Use `Excel.Workbooks.Worksheets` rather than the `Sheets` collection.
- Rather than looping through all the worksheets, try to reference the one you want, using error-handling to determine if the sheet exists:

  ```
  Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets["SheetName"];
  ```

Avoid `Select`, it is rarely necessary - and slow. Replace,

```
//Select all cells, and clear the contents
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myAllRange = worksheet.Cells;
myAllRange.Select();
myAllRange.CurrentRegion.Select();
myAllRange.ClearContents();
```

with

```
worksheet.UsedRange.ClearContents();
```

You should be able to remove your function `SelectAllUsedCells()` entirely. If you still needed to select them, then:

```
worksheet.UsedRange.Select();    // but shouldn't be necessary
```

Otherwise, if you stick with looping through the worksheets, use `break;` once you've found the sheet, to exit the loop.

Delete `rng.Select();` from your **fillExcelCell()** function. However, you appear to be calling this function for every cell; is this correct? I would do all the formatting in one go afterwards. In particular, applying `AutoFit` to the entire range.

I would create the shape once and copy/paste it. (Not sure if it can be *cloned*?)

Put the Calcuation mode back to its original setting when complete.

Answer (score 7):

You are processing one cell at a time. The `Range` Excel object can represent a two-dimensional grid.

1. You can either build an array in .NET and set the `Value` in one shot.
2. My preference is to do it by columns. So that data and formatting
   can be contained in one logical unit.

Answer (score 2):

I apologize for not answering your exact question, but I'd like to pass a piece of advice here.

Using Interop in this way is very slow by nature: communication between applications is not the fastest thing in Windows, and Excel is doing a lot of things you don't need at each operation, even if Andy G has provided you some hints to limit its overhead.

A solid solution is *not* to use Excel to export data: use a .net library such as Aspose.Cells or any other one. Aspose.Cells is a bit expensive but it's very good. Note that I have no interest in Aspose, I've just used it in several of my projects. I've used Syncfusion as well, cheaper and good but a less intuitive API in my opinion. There are other ones, including the free MS OpenXml Library, which is free but *very* low level (I wouldn't advise it).

With such libraries it's very easy to export data to an Excel file and the performance is excellent.